# Mutex in Obj-c / Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa, locking, mutex

I'm pretty new to multithreaded programming & cocoa.

I'm going to need a lock to access/modify a `NSMutableArray` iVar. What's the simpliest way to do it ?

And while I'm here, do you guys have some reading about multithreaded programming with Obj-c/Cocoa ? 
Thx.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the `@synchronized` block:

```
@synchronized(MyArray)
{
    // thread safe code
}
```

This block is not recognized by Xcode at times, but trust me, it works!

For more information, you can read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html) article.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method is to use GCD and serial queues.

For your NSArray property, write accessors that use a private serial queue. to set, and fetch the values from the backing store. Since serial queues Are FIFO, and will run the blocks sequentially this provides thread safe access to the property.

Comment: Could you be more explicit with some example ? Thx!

Comment: something like __block id val = nil; dispatch_sync(aQueue, ^{ val = [array objectAtIndex:index]; }); to get a value, and dispatch_sync(aQueue, ^{ [array addObject:obj]; }); for the setter.

Comment: Be careful with `dispatch_sync`! If called from the current queue, it will result in a deadlock.

Comment: You wouldn't dispatch_sync onto the current queue for serialization anyway. You'd dispatch_sync onto a private queue specifically for that purpose.